# What types of charts should I use for each statistical variable, ordinal, nominal, discrete, continuous

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am finishing my homework and I need to include some charts. I heard somewhere that different variables require different types of charts. I have the following variables, ordinal, nominal, discrete and continuous. I am very bad at charts, I don't know them. It seems that if the bars in a bar chart are side by side or spaced out matters and so on. I would like that you specify the chart and how it should be

After a post the question and I am researching. It seems that spaces are used between the bars of discrete variable, continuous variables have the bars close together. Is that right? I still want a complete answer.

Comment: I encourage you to visit this website for a comprehensive review on data types and charts: https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/data-types/  Feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: You may find different people have different preferences, and in some cases preferences change depending on specific data and objective. My general preferences are: pie for nominal, bar for ordinal, histogram for numerical. Exceptions might be to use pie if it's important to show that proportions in favor (somewhat or strongly) exceed proportions opposed; to use bar chart for discrete data if it's important to illustrate discreteness. (Availability of color or need to print exact counts may also make a difference. Also, statistical sophistication of audience may be a factor.)